# 64 bit Random number value in hex gives 16 characters sometimes 15 characters why?

Tags: java, hex, long-integer

I have scenario in the application where I need to generate an ID which should be Random 64 bit value in hex representation,

What I have done so far,

```
 Random randomLong = new Random();
 long m = randomLong.nextLong();
 String uid = Long.toHexString(m);
```

The o/p could be like **43c45c243f90326a** or **82cf8e3863102f3a** etc.
But not every time it gives 16 character, but 15 characters instead I don't get why :(

What is the most efficient way to get Random 64 bit value in hex representation which contains 16 characters

Comment: because toHExString is not adding leading zeros to the random number

Comment: Use `String.format("%016x", longValue)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use String.format()

```
long value=123L;
String uid = String.format("%016x", value);
// 000000000000007b
```

A word of explanation:

Each hex digit represents 4-bits.  A 64-bit long can be represented by 16 (64/4) hexadecimal characters.  To include the leading zeros, you want 16 hex digits.  So your format specifier is `%016x`.  Basically, `%x` for hex modified by inserting `016` to left-pad with zeros to achieve a minimum width of 16 characters.

Comment: Could you add a word of explanation, why this works? Please have a look at [answer].

Comment: Thanks, its a nice explanation got it.

Answer (score 1):

this is because the method toHExString is not adding leading zeros to the random number you are converting, if the number can be represented with only one char as hex, then one char is what you get

see this

```
    String uid = Long.toHexString(-1L);
    String uid2 = Long.toHexString(1L);
    System.out.println(uid);
    System.out.println(uid2);
```

the output is

> ffffffffffffffff
>
> 1

-1 will require the 64 bits to be represented but 1 doesnt

edit:

if you always need 16 nibbles then format that string in order to add the missing zeros

```
 String uid = String.format("%016x", Long.toHexString(1L));
```

Comment: I could do this but to be honest didn't get the meaning of it, what do you mean to say by if the number can be represented with only one char as hex, then one char is what you get

Comment: a long var with the value 255 can be represented as 0xFF instead of 0x00000000000000FF

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("%016x", uid);
```

This will add the leading 0's, or 'padding'
as if the hex number is smaller than filling all 16, it wont show 16 digits.

[image]